# Changing the width value of a javascript variable with css

Tags: javascript, css, variables, width, responsive-design

I have the following code in my javascript :

```
var demoSlider_3 = Sliderman.slider({container: 'SliderName_3', 
                                     width: 167, 
                                     height: 250, 
                                     effects: effectsDemo3, 
                                     display: { autoplay: 4000 }
                                    });
```

What I'm trying to do is to set the width and the height in the CSS file (I'm trying to make it responsive).

For now i haven't find the solution... 

so if anybody has a clue I'll appreciate your help !

Thank you

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but wouldn't it be better to have the style defined in CSS and just make the Javascript _switch style_ instead of setting hard coded values?

Comment: "Changing the width value of a javascript varaible with css" You can't set a script variable using CSS, because the latter isn't a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the initial width height via CSS and read it from the element, which should become the slider, via JavaScript. It doesn't matter if you use inline styles, a CSS-class or whatever to style the element. You just need to read the computed values and use them in the slider initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to make something I was adding in to a page using JavaScript respond to a particular element's dimensions I would usually use width = '100%' height = '100%' and then tailor my wrapping element with css so that it has a defined width and height.

Example (using jQuery for simplicity):

css:

```
.wrapper { width: 300px; height: 300px; }
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  var myElementToEmbed = $('<div />').css({width:'100%',height:'100%'});
  var targetWrapper = $('.wrapper');
  targetWrapper.append( myElementToEmbed );
});
```

dom:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

That way the JavaScript deals with the functional workings *(as it should)* and the CSS deals with the styling of display *(as it should)*.

Comment: …and you have one useless element more. Why to use wrapper, if you could style the slider element directly via its ID (`SliderName_3`)?

Comment: ... because you have no way of knowing exactly how the internal embed/plugin will handle defining it's dimensions... if you have - as the OP states - a constructor like `Sliderman.slider` if you don't pass dimensioning information it may use defaults, overriding the ones you've defined in CSS *(please don't advocating the use of !important)*. There is barely any overhead by defining a wrapping element and it gives you extra leverage from what you can do easily in CSS. Obviously my example above is for illustrative purposes only, you would not use this to embed a plain old div element.

Comment: Thanks all for your return. I'll test what you recommanded to me ! :-)